# How to increase Variable size limit in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to set a variable by executing e.g.

```
SET Variable_1 = 'xxxx'
```

, but am getting this error:

> "Assignment to 'Variable_1' not done because value exceeds size limit for variables. Its size is 309; the limit is 256 (internal storage size in bytes)."

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach could be using variable defined inside Snowflake Scripting block:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t(s STRING);

SET long_variable  = '
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
';
```

> Assignment to 'LONG_VARIABLE' not done because value exceeds size limit for variables. Its size is 288; the limit is 256 (internal storage size in bytes)

The same string literal:

```
DECLARE
  LONG_VARIABLE STRING DEFAULT '
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
';

  SQL STRING DEFAULT 'INSERT INTO t(s) VALUES(?)'; 
BEGIN    
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :SQL USING (LONG_VARIABLE);
   RETURN :SQL;
END;
```

Output:

```
SELECT LENGTH(s), s FROM t;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, that's the limit:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/session-variables.html#initializing-variables

That said, depending on what you are using them for, you could potentially use multiple variables (and concatenate them when you use them) or store the values in a temporary table (and look them up when you need them).