# Create Snowflake Query with Variables of defined Length?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I know I can do this in a stored procedure. However, whenever I am just creating a a basic query, all Snowflake lets me use is the "Set vParmeter1 = "; command this limits me to the 256 characters which is limiting. I know varchar can go up to 16mb, as in DECLARE vParameter VARCHAR(16777216); I have used this in my procedures. What I cannot figure out is how to use it in a script. I have been trying combination of what works and what "should" work but for some reason Snowflake enjoyed rewriting how to do the SQL books. Below my code errors out and the VARCHAR(), if you comment out the Declare it works. The 2nd set that is commented out I saw someone else using so I had tried, but it never got there so I left it off. The error is EOF line 1, right at the last 6 in the varchar size. I also tried reducing the varchar size to 30 or so but just changed the error location.

```
  DECLARE   vParameter1 VARCHAR(16777216);

SET vParameter1 = '700,145,138,159';
--SET vParameter1 := '700,145,138,159';

SELECT TO_NUMBER(table1.VALUE) AS Locations
FROM TABLE(SPLIT_to_table($vParameter1,',')) AS table1
```

Below is the final final answer that worked for me on my machine, based on the the help for the upvoted answer.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
DECLARE 
  vParameter1 VARCHAR(16777216) := '700,145,138,159';
  res RESULTSET;
BEGIN 
  -- alternative to declare block
  -- LET vParameter1 VARCHAR(16777216) := '700,145,138,159'; 
 
  res := (
    SELECT TO_NUMBER(table1.VALUE) AS Locations
    FROM TABLE(SPLIT_to_table(:vParameter1,',')) AS table1
  );

  /* -- if no resultset is expected then simply:
  INSERT INTO some_table(col)
  SELECT TO_NUMBER(table1.VALUE) AS Locations
  FROM TABLE(SPLIT_to_table(:vParameter1,',')) AS table1;
  */

  RETURN TABLE(res);
END;
$$;
```

Comment: I actually had that exact one open for about the last hour and really did not understand it. Any chance I can bribe you with Karma to rewrite the above query format? I am assuming tables aren't mandatory. That was just in that example. I have about 10 variable in my real query some using the Split and some just single value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session variables (`SET`) != Block variables (`DECLARE/LET`). Session variables have hard limit of 256 bytes.

Using a block variable:

```
DECLARE 
  vParameter1 VARCHAR(16777216) := '700,145,138,159';
  res RESULTSET;
BEGIN 
  -- alternative to declare block
  -- LET vParameter1 VARCHAR(16777216) := '700,145,138,159'; 
 
  res := (
    SELECT TO_NUMBER(table1.VALUE) AS Locations
    FROM TABLE(SPLIT_to_table(:vParameter1,',')) AS table1
  );

  /* -- if no resultset is expected then simply:
  INSERT INTO some_table(col)
  SELECT TO_NUMBER(table1.VALUE) AS Locations
  FROM TABLE(SPLIT_to_table(:vParameter1,',')) AS table1;
  */

  RETURN TABLE(res);
END;
```

Output:

[image]

Related:

- [Returning `RESULTSET`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/resultsets)
- [Using a Variable in a SQL Statement (Binding)](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/variables#using-a-variable-in-a-sql-statement-binding)
- [How to increase Variable size limit in Snowflake?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70997220/5070879)

Comment: Hmm Still getting an error on Line 2, tried in both Snowflake web and Dbeaver.
SQL compilation error: syntax error line 2 at position 53 unexpected '<EOF>'.

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/running-examples - Please try Snowsight UI or `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  $$ <block here> $$`;

Comment: These snowflake people are insane. Thanks so much for you help. Why anyone goes to their product I will never know. thank you so much.